# The precise definition of a number of e-folds in inflationary theory

Tags: cosmological-inflation

Cosmological parameters and their correspondence with recent data are very important, so I have two basic questions, what is the exact meaning and definition of the number of e-folds, and for what purpose was it introduced? And why the slow roll parameters should be very small in the inflationary period

Comment: $H=\frac{d}{dt}\ln a$ is the rate of $e$-folds in $a$. Could you restate your question about slow roll parameters in terms of notation such as e.g. used [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109369)?

Comment: Thanks, but I want a non-mathematical definition of it. What does it mean to say 50 or 60 e-folds? without an equation?

Comment: Does "the universe's length scale multiplying by $e^{50}$ or $e^{60}$" count as "without an equation"?